# "Conflito" de ID dentro do Datalist

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, webforms

Boa tarde a todos. Bem, tenho um datalist. Ai coloquei um repeater dentro, até ai tudo bem. Mas ai na hora em que executo, só o primeiro repeater aparece estilizado do jeito que quero. O resto acho que deve mudar o id, e acaba aparecendo sem formatação.
Bom pelo que parece, dever ser meus links do JQuery e JCarousel que estão dando esse problema. Mas ainda não sei como resolver. Alguém teria alguma dica, uma luz para me mostrar?
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jcarousel/0.2.8/jquery.jcarousel.min.js

```
//Eis o código do meu datalist

 <asp:DataList ID="dlCustomers" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnItemDataBound="dlCustomers_ItemDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="85%">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tipo") %>' visible="false"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblImagem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Imagem") %>' Visible="False" />
                    <img src="<%# Eval("Caminho") + "" +Eval("Imagem") %>" width="200px" height="130px" id="imgPro"/>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="CodigoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Codigo") %>' Visible="False" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPro" runat="server" CssClass="but" Text='<%# Eval("Descriçao") %>' href='<%# "Categorias.aspx?Codigo=" + Eval("Codigo") + "&Tipo=" + Eval("Tipo") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAlterar" runat="server" Text="Alterar" Visible="False" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir um grupo?');"  Text="Excluir" Visible="False" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnVisivel" runat="server" Height="21px"  Text="Visibilidade" Width="93px" Visible="False" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <img alt="" style='height: 75px; width: 75px' src='<%# Eval("Caminho") + "" +Eval("Imagem") %>' />
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Olá Vinícius. Pode postar também o CSS do seu repeater?

Comment: Vinícius, você tentou usar `class` ao invés de `id` para estilizar os componentes?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script><link http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jcarousel/0.2.8/skins/tango/skin.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jcarousel/0.2.8/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script> é dai onde tem meu css, jquery.....

Comment: @GuilhermedeJesusSantos não tem ideia do que possar ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, depois de muita busca em grupos do Facebook, fóruns, eu consegui a resposta. No fórum aspforums.net um rapaz me ajudou. Me sugeriu mudar essa linha de código

```
$(function () {
     $ ( "# Mycarousel ') jcarousel (.);    
});
```

Por essa

```
$(function () {
     $('[id*=mycarousel]').jcarousel();
});
```

Então fica aí a resposta, para caso alguém precise de ajuda. E obrigado aos que tiraram um tempinho para tentar ajudar.

Comment: Realmente se você usava a primeira função, `$ ( "# Mycarousel ') jcarousel (.); ` ela contém erros de sintaxe. A sintaxe correta seria : `$('#mycarousel').jcarousel();`.